# ASP.Net MVC routes confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have the following URLs for my ASP.Net MVC 2 site:

```
http://localhost:1919/TimeEntry/SummaryForWeek/15/2011

http://localhost:1919/TimeEntry/SummaryForMonth/4/2011
```

Both of these are hitting this route:

```
            routes.MapRoute
        (
            "TimeEntryActionMonthYear", // Route name
            "TimeEntry/{action}/{month}/{year}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "TimeEntry", action = "Summary", month = UrlParameter.Optional, year = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The action for SummaryForWeek is expecting a parameter named "weekNumber" (the 15 value in URL above) whereas the route that is being used is passing a parameter called "month" and consequently the URL for weekSummary fails.  It doesn't make sense to rename the parameter for SummaryForWeek from week to month just so the route works.

Should I add a Route to route table where {action} is hardcoded for "SummaryForWeeks"?  This doesn't make sense either as it bloats the route table.

What am I not understanding (I know this opens me up for some creative comments)?  I'm stuck.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Binding problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743223/asp-net-mvc-routing-id-parameter/4304147#4304147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need two routes, or you need a more generic name for your parameters:

```
TimeEntry/{action}/{subdivision}/{year}
```

or something similar. Then both actions would have to take these two parameters, one would interpret as month, the other as week.

Comment: i think this is the route I have to take.  This sucks actually.  The processor should be able to identify the action from the URL, find the action in the controller, then start matching parameters in the order they appear in the URL to the parameter signature of the action.  This way, you don't have to worry about naming issues.  Is this the wrong way to look at it?  Thanks for your help.